# Apple AppStore Reject

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, app-store, appstore-approval

Does Apple reject iPhone/iPad Apps because of using Third Prty APIs..

Comment: It seems you are new to Stack Overflow. Please mark the answer you accept with a click on the "√". Thanks!

Comment: If they did, what'd be the point of the App Store?

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Apple never rejects application because of third party APIs. If you use any PRIVATE API of apple, it invariably gets rejected.

Google maps, google analytics, google weather, UAStoreFront, Authorize.net etc. are third parties which provide their own APIs for specfic functionality's and lots and lots of applications are there on the app-store which use these APIs

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by "third party APIs"?
I assume you mean *third party libraries*, as in classes and code written by someone else which you use in your own app.

No. They don't reject your app because of that. They do if that said 3rd party code uses Apple private APIs or does something else that is against the rules of the app store - but if that's not the case, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Only if those APIs are using private APIs (undocumented method from the iOS SDK). So, Three20 for example is allowed

Comment: Can we use PayPal API or framework in application

Answer (score 2):

If you are using private libraries (methods that are undocumented from SDK), they'll reject your app but if you are using third party libraries documented, your app will go live on the app store.

Answer (score 1):

If by third party apis you mean libraries which you compile and statically link into your app then no they don't.

But if you use undocumented IOS APIs then your app will be rejected.

Comment: Can we use PayPal API or framework in application ?