# Apple rejected my app Guideline 5.2.2 - Legal

Tags: appstore-approval

I build an app using the official Zoom SDK with the intention to publish it in the Apple App Store for iOS.

Apple rejected the app saying:

> Guideline 5.2.2 - Legal
>
> Although Zoom Video Communications, Inc. may allow the general public to use their service, we still require the documentary evidence that you have all the necessary rights or permissions to request, display, or distribute account information in your application.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please attach documentary evidence in the App Review Information section in App Store Connect. In accordance with section 3.2(f) of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement, you acknowledge that submitting falsified or fraudulent documentation can result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account and the removal of your apps from the App Store. Once Legal has reviewed your documentation and confirms its validity, we will proceed with the review of your app.

I want to work with them to get this app published and I want to avoid endless feedback a review looks. And so I replied in the resolution center that I don't understand how I can comply and whom I shall ask for what written permission. I suggested that we could have a brief phone call. So far I'm waiting for Apple's reaction...

From what I understand Apple wants me to go to Zoom to ask for written permission to use their SDK. Am I correct? (Imagine every developer that uses some publicly available SDK has to ask the publisher for written permission). Or what exact steps are required to get this resolved?

I found this here: [Apple AppStore Reject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297029/apple-appstore-reject) and from what I understand there should be no issues with using an SDK. Very frustrating. I don't want to argue, I want to comply. But I don't know how and what to do?

Just found this: https://medium.com/swlh/my-app-is-dead-in-the-water-93a97a137eff

Matt wrote as an update:

> Edit 11/20/18: Hacker News Zero has been approved! It seems like the attention this article got had some sort of effect at Apple App Review HQ. Thanks everyone for your support!

Comment: Does the Zoom SDK you are using have a EULA or other similar information contained in it?  That text, if present, should explain the terms of acceptable use for you or a user of your application.  All you should need to do is include that and a description of how you have complied with Zoom's terms and you should be good to go.

Comment: "request, display, or distribute *account information* " - this looks like more than just using a public API, are you requesting user to enter any *Zoom* account details for the use of the service?

Comment: @paxdiablo Actually I don't ask for any user information at this time. And even if I don't see how that would be the problem.

Comment: @jwh20 - thank you for this hint. I'm not sure I understand what you mean but I found this: https://zoom.us/privacy-and-legal - which one are you referring to?

Comment: @takendarkk - that's how https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/user-login#non-login

Comment: Also here: https://zoom.us/service it says: you can use Services to do a number of things, such as: develop integrations to connect other tools to or build packaged solutions for Zoom, create chatbots, manage Zoom services programmatically, embed Zoom in your desktop, web or mobile application, and more.

Comment: Last but not least: https://zoom.us/docs/en-us/zoom_api_license_and_tou.html

Comment: Our license agreement to use the SDK https://github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-ios/blob/master/LICENSE.md

Comment: Questions regarding the opaque processes of app stores to permit the publishing of the app are probably off-topic, since readers won't have the necessary (non-public) criteria information to hand. This is a customer service issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the app accepted with this github.com/zoom/zoom-sdk-ios/blob/master/LICENSE.md